# how to conclude this set is compact?

Tags: general-topology

how to conclude this set is  compact?

> $X=\{(x,y):x>0,y=\sin(1/x)\}\cap\{(x,y):x>0,y=1/x\}$

and my second question  is  $$\{(x,y):y=0,\sin(e^{-x})=0\}$$  compact?

Other than drawing pictures, though I am not quite sure how will be the picture.

Comment: Show they are closed and bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that the first set is actually finite, and the second set is unbounded.

Comment: I'm not sure the first set is finite...is it easy to see it is?

Comment: @DonAntonio All the intersections must have $x\geq 1$, and then $\sin(z) = z$ only has finitely many solutions in $(0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

Since $1/x\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow0^{+}$ and $\sin(x)$ is bounded we have that, for some $a$,

$$X=\{(x,y):x\geq a,y=\sin(1/x)\}\cap\{(x,y):x\geq a,y=1/x\}.$$

Now, since $\sin(x)\leq x$ for $|x|$ small we have that for some $b$

$$X=\{(x,y):b\geq x\geq a,y=\sin(1/x)\}\cap\{(x,y):b\geq x\geq a,y=1/x\}.$$

Hence the two sets being intersected are closed and bounded.